# How to update select option from Jquery Ajax successful data

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

When I click the button I am getting console output correctly ; but my options are not getting updated. Please help as I new to Ajax, Jquery and Django. I spent more than a week to fix the issues. But no result.

My Django code:

```py
# model
class Post(models.Model):
    post_heading = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    post_text = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_heading

# view
def getmydata(request):
    # get the provinces for given country from the
    # database excluding null and blank values

    if request.method == "GET" :
       data = list(Post.objects.all().values())
       return JsonResponse({"data": data})
```

my html template is:

```html
    <div >
        <select name="car_maker" id="car_maker">
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="postacct">
        <p>>{{ acct.post_heading }}</p>>
        </div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.clickme').click(function(){
        let catid;
        {#catid = $(this).attr("data-catid");#}
        catid='nil'
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: "/getmydata",
            data: {
                post_id: catid,
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'
            },
            success: function (data) {

                
                console.log(data);
                $("#car_maker option").remove();

                $.each(data.rows, function (index, item) { //jQuery way of iterating through a collection
                    $("#car_maker option").append($('<option>')
                        .text(item.label)
                        .attr('value', item.value));
                })
            }
        })})
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

From ajax I getting the console output:

```
(index):54 

{data: Array(2)}

data: Array(2)s
0: {id: 1, post_heading: "2", post_text: "two"}
1: {id: 2, post_heading: "1", post_text: "one"}
length: 2
```

Comment: There are no `label` or `value` properties in that response data. Use the appropriate key names

Comment: Also can't append option to another option. Selector should just be for the select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reconstruct your code.

```
<select name="car_maker" id="car_maker">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

With your response

```js
var data = {
  "data": [{
    'id': 1,
    'post_heading': '2',
    'post_text': 'two'
  }, {
    'id': 2,
    'post_heading': '1',
    'post_text': 'one'

  }]
}

console.log(data);

$("#car_maker option").remove();

$.each(data, function(index, item) {
  console.log('test', item[0].post_heading);
  console.log('test', item[1].post_text);
  $.each(item, function(index1, item1) {
    console.log(item1.id);
    console.log(item1.post_heading);
    console.log(item1.post_text);
    $('#car_maker').append($('<option/>', {
      value: item1.id,
      text: item1.post_text
    }));
  })
});
```

Comment: test undefined ;test undefined;  I am getting these responses for console.log('test', item.post_heading) and console.log('test', item.post_text);

Comment: test it again. Runs in fiddle.

Comment: I tried again but i am getting undefined _but I change the code as : console.log('test', item[0].post_heading) I am getting first post_heading.

Comment: I tried again but i am getting undefined _but I change the code as : console.log('test', item[0].post_heading) I am getting first post_heading. for your reference :my data printed in console is:data: Array(2)
0: {id: 1, post_heading: "2", post_text: "two"}
1: {id: 2, post_heading: "1", post_text: "one"}. Do I  any mistake in my views :if request.method == "GET" :
       data = list(Post.objects.all().values())
       return JsonResponse({"data": data}) :Needs your valuable help.

Comment: updated my answer. Just test it. Should work now. I don't know your JSON Structure. Just guess it.

Comment: Please guide can we make it as a single loop; Data is from model as seen in view. Tks.

Comment: Please check it as answered. So I get some points. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with single loop. You have an array of objects.